# Graal VM Error: zsh: segmentation fault ./hello

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I encountered an issue while running a simple Java program after compiling it with GraalVM and generating a native image. The original Java file is named Hello.java and contains the following code:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

To compile the code, I used GraalVM, which resulted in the generation of the Hello.class file. Subsequently, I created a native image for this class using the command `native-image Hello`. However, when attempting to execute the program with the ./hello command, I encountered the following error:

```
zsh: segmentation fault  ./hello`
```

Despite searching for solutions on Stack Overflow, I have been unable to find a suitable resolution.

Here are the system and GraalVM installation details:

```
OS: MacOS Ventura
Processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
GraalVM: graalvm-jdk-17.0.7+8.1 
(Dowloaded it from https://www.graalvm.org/downloads with Java 17 and macOS(x64))
```

Below is the output for`java -version`

```
java version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 17.0.7+8.1 (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-jvmci-23.0-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 17.0.7+8.1 (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-jvmci-23.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Would really appreciate if someone can help me on this issue.

Comment: You might have hit [this issue](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/6796)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is a known issue for GraalVM. https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/5778

As per the issue on Github, I was able to resolve the `zsh: segmentation fault ./hello` problem using below workaround:

1. Obtain an older version of Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode%2012.5.1 This requires an Apple ID. (If you are not comfortable clicking the link, just sign in to Apple Developer account and search for "Xcode 12.5.1")
2. Unpack it via finder
3. Open a terminal and run following commands

```
$ mv ~/Downloads/Xcode.app /Applications/Xcode12.5.1.app/
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode12.5.1.app/Contents/Developer
$ # verify with
$ xcodebuild -version
```

4. Now if we generate and run the native image again, it successfully runs.